# how to get object from listview in setOnItemClickListener in android?

Tags: android, android-adapterview

I have added arraylist in arrayadapter which contains objects each consists of two elements/items, I have successfully set that adapter for setListAdapter, now i want to get those items in setOnItemClickListener of listview.

here is my code

```
   TweetListAdaptor adaptor = new TweetListAdaptor(this,R.layout.list_item, tweets);       
   setListAdapter(adaptor); 
   ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
   {
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
   {
     //here i want to get the items             
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 57):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    int color = parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id){
    something = tweets[position];
}
```

Comment: apparently that's the only solution

Answer (score 2):

You want to get the items and do what with them?

For example, you can make a Toast message like this.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tweets[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

and if you have the listview ready with all datas and want get a value of a objet only use:

```
ViewGroup row = (ViewGroup) listprod.getChildAt(0);
TextView tvTest = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textnomprod);
```

Where my listview is "**listprod**" and i want get the value in the position **0**, where **textnomprod** is my objet and im saving in my variable **tvTest**

Answer (score 0):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
        Windows clickedObject = adapter.get(position);
    }
}
```

Consider in the example above,

- object used in the listview is named **Windows**,
- the object of the item clicked in the listview is named **clickedObject**,
- the arraylist used is called **adapter**.

Also, make sure to prefix your ArrayList with *final*.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using its adapter that was set to it.

```
TweetListAdaptor adaptor = new TweetListAdaptor(this,R.layout.list_item, tweets);       
setListAdapter(adaptor); 
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) 
   {    
        //here i want to get the items  
        adaptor.getItem(position);   // this is your object
    }
});
```

Just keep in mind that the adapter must be initialized and set to the ListView.

In this way, you can access the properties of the object you want.

Answer (score -2):

`getListView().getItemAtPosition(position)` will return an `Object` in your `TweetListAdaptor`